# SKAction.resize doesn't work

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift4.2

I want to resize a SKShapeNode with SKAction while the node is moving (with another SKAction), but it didn't work out. I tried only resizing and it failed too (nothing happened).
That's what I did:

```
background.run(SKAction.resize(toWidth: winFrame.width/20, height: winFrame.height/20, duration: 0.5))
background.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: winFrame.width*0.97 / -2, y: -1*(winFrame.height/7) * 1.5), duration: 0.5))
```

what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try calling:

```
SKAction.scale(by: CGFloat, duration: TimeInterval)
```

Instead of resizing the node

Answer (score 2):

If you read the documents, it says that `.resize` only works with SKSpriteNodes.

> This action can only be executed by an SKSpriteNode object. When the
>   action executes, the sprite’s size property animates to its new value.
>
> This action is not reversible; the reverse of this action has the same
>   duration but does not change anything.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417724-resize